# List of Body Classes Generated by body_class()

Tags: functions, post-class, references

Does anyone know where I can get a *list of all the **body classes*** generated by `body_class()` for **every sections** and **every conditions**, including *custom post-types*, etc.?

For example, for a *search result* page with certain conditions (eg. *logged-in*), the function produces this:

```
<body class="search search-results logged-in admin-bar single-author two-column right-sidebar">
```

I need the full list for **reference** in creating a theme.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several classes have been added since WordPress 2.8 (when the WPEngineer post was written). I would refer directly to the [`body_class()` Codex entry](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class), which currently lists the following:

- rtl
- home
- blog
- archive
- date
- search
- paged
- attachment
- error404
- single postid-(id)
- page-id-(page_id)
- attachmentid-(id)
- attachment-(mime-type)
- author
- author-(user_nicename)
- category
- category-(slug)
- tag
- tag-(slug)
- page-parent
- page-child parent-pageid-(id)
- page-template page-template-(template file name)
- search-results
- search-no-results
- logged-in
- paged-(page number)
- single-paged-(page number)
- page-paged-(page number)
- category-paged-(page number)
- tag-paged-(page number)
- date-paged-(page number)
- author-paged-(page number)
- search-paged-(page number)
- tax-(taxonomy name) (since 3.1)
- term-(term name) (since 3.1)
- admin-bar (since 3.1)

Comment: (Also @Hiranthi) Cheers! But do you know if _body_class()_ also generates specific classes for **custom post-types** as well?

Comment: It appears that it does *not*; however, if you're using a custom `single-{posttype}.php` template file, then you get a `single-{posttype}` class.

Comment: Plugins can of course hook into `body_class` and add an unlimited number of extra classes, so this list can only contain the classes added by WP core code.

Comment: The Codex entry (and thus this list) should be updated, I see that post formats and post type archives also generate body classes. Someone should [check the source](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.2/wp-includes/post-template.php?annotate=blame&rev=18415#L401) and add the missing classes.

Answer (score 1):

There's a list of that on [WPEngineer.com](http://wpengineer.com/816/wordpress-28-body_class-automatic_feed_links/)